# jQuery .attr('id') returns empty

Tags: jquery, attr

Here is my code

```
    $('.sort').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        $.cookie('sortby', $(this).attr('id'), { expires: 25 });
        //window.location.reload(true);
    });
```

HTML

```
<button id="name" class="sort">Name</button> 
<button id="price" class="sort">Price</button> 
<button id="popular" class="sort">Popularity</button>
```

My cookie ends up empty and the console shows up as

```
popular
(an empty string)
```

It seems it is getting the correct id but then changing it to null
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using 1.6 you should now be using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Just a note: an "empty string" is not stricly a null

Comment: @Claudio: I could be wrong, but I think "(an empty string)" is how the OP is displaying, literally, an empty string as an absence of a value wouldn't drive the point. ;-)

Comment: your right, it's not strictly null, but 'null' is much easier to type then '(an empty string)' but now that I am explaining this it seems a moot point...In the console it literally says '(an empty string)' right under the proper value

Comment: Can you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem with minimal code?

Comment: Personally, I can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/bATVf/

Comment: Could you log the cookie value to the console after setting it? How did you check if it was set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second call the $(this) object has changed scope. The following should work:

```
    $('.sort').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        var $this = $(this);
        $.cookie('sortby', $this.attr('id'), { expires: 25 });
        //window.location.reload(true);
    });
```

Comment: I really don't see the difference. Are you sure? -1

Comment: OPs not in a code block, so I don't believe scope really applies here. (Maybe I'm wrong) Evaluation order would take care of executing (and returning) the `.attr()` value, _then_ pass it on to `$.cookie`

Comment: It worked for a little bit, but then it ended up doing the same thing :/

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because your inside cookie when you refer to 'this' try instead

```
$('.sort').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    $.cookie('sortby', id, { expires: 25 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your code is going wrong, as I [can not reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/bATVf/) the issue.

I would look in to making sure the `$.cookie` library is loading and make sure things are good on that end.